# Adding a context menu item to OpenFileDialog

Tags: wpf, user-interface

I'm using `Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog` dlg in my WPF application. Is there any way to add a context menu item to `Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog` and to handle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in functionality for that. I suppose you could do that using some scary run-time code injection techniques but that would be bothersome and hard to maintain further down the road.

What you can do, though, is create own OpenFileDialog (or peek at it's sources) and add necessary context menu item. It's implementation is easy in wpf (with TreeView for showing folder structure).